# How to import files in an existing subversion repo?

Tags: svn

The example given in svnbook is with a new repo:

```
$ svnadmin create /var/svn/newrepos
$ svn import mytree file:///var/svn/newrepos/some/project \
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 # svn mkdir file:///root/svn-repository/etc \
     -m "Make a directory in the repository to correspond to /etc"
 # cd /etc
 # svn checkout file:///root/svn-repository/etc .
 # svn add apache samba alsa X11 
 # svn commit -m "Initial version of my config files"
```

This takes advantage of a not-immediately-obvious feature of svn checkout: you can check out a directory from the repository directly into an existing directory. Here, we first make a new empty directory in the repository, and then check it out into /etc, transforming /etc into a working copy. Once that is done, you can use normal svn add commands to select files and subtrees to add to the repository.

Reference http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#cvs2svn

Comment: What's diff with
svn import projectmidi_src 
    file:///c:/SvnRepos/ProjectMidi -m "initial import"

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/SubversionOnWindows.aspx